# Split large gzip file while adding header line to each split

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

I want to automate the process of splitting large `gzip` file to smaller `gzip` file each split containing `10000000` lines (Last split will be left over and will less than 10000000).

Here is how I am doing at the moment and I am actually repeating by calculating number of left over lines.

```
gunzip -c large_gzip_file.txt.gz | tail -n +10000001 | head -n 10000000 > split1_.txt 
gzip split1_.txt

gunzip -c large_gzip_file.txt.gz | tail -n +20000001 | head -n 10000000 > split2_.txt 
gzip split2_.txt
```

I continue this by repeating as shown all the way until the end. Then I open these and manually add the header line. How can this be automated.

I search online where i see `awk` and other solutions but didn't see for gzip or similar to this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach it like this:

1. `gunzip` the file
2. use `head` to get the first line and save it off to another file
3. use `tail` to get the rest of the file and pipe it to `split` to produce files of 10,000,000 lines each
4. use `sed` to insert the header into each file, or just cat the header with each file
5. gzip each file

You'll want to wrap this in a script or a function to make it easier to rerun at a later time. Here's an attempt at a solution, lightly tested:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -euo pipefail

LINES=10000000

file=$(basename $1 .gz)

gunzip -k ${file}.gz
head -n 1 $file >header.txt
tail -n +2 $file | split -l $LINES - ${file}.part.
rm -f $file

for part in ${file}.part.* ; do
  [[ $part == *.gz ]] && continue # ignore partial results of previous runs

  gzip -c header.txt $part >${part}.gz

  rm -f $part
done

rm -f header.txt
```

To use:

```
$ ./splitter.sh large_gzip_file.txt.gz
```

I would further improve this by using a temporary directory (`mktemp -d`) for the intermediate files and ensuring the script cleans up after itself at exit (with a `trap`). Ideally it would also sanity check the arguments, possibly accepting a second argument indicating the number of lines per part, and inspect the contents of the current directory to ensure it doesn't clobber any preexisting files.

Comment: assume i put this in x.sh file. can i do arguments when executing. Is it possible for example on that too. Thanks

Comment: What arguments would you want? There are plenty of examples on StackOverflow of shell scripts that accept arguments if that's all you need.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `awk` is for splitting gzip file into smaller pieces files, it's for text-processing. Below is my way to solve your issue, hope it helps:

**step1:**

```
gunzip -c large_gzip_file.txt.gz | split -l 10000000 - split_file_
```

`split` command can split a file into pieces, you can specify the size of each piece and also provide prefix for all pieces.

the large gzip file will be splited to multiple files with name prefix `split_file_`

**step2**:

save header content into file header_file.csv

**step3:**

```
for f in split_file*; do
  cat header_file.csv $f > $f.new
  mv $f.new $f
done
```

Here I assume you work in the splited file directory, if not, replace `split_file*` with the absolute path, for example `/path/to/split_file*`.  Iterates all files with name pattern `split_file*`, add header content to the beginning of each match file

Comment: step one doest work its saying non such file or directory

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis replace `large_gzip_file.txt.gz` with the real gzipped file name if you execute the command under the same directory of the file

Comment: its complain the `split_file_` new file name `gunzip -c large_gzip_file.txt.gz | split -l 10000000 split_file_`

Comment: my bad.  forgot `-`.  It is `gunzip -c large_gzip_file.txt.gz | split -l 10000000 - split_file_`